# If CDN server controls cache expire, what is the default value?

Tags: javascript, caching, cdn

It is recommended that we use CDN for third party libraries like (Bootstrap, JQuery) etc.
But when we use CDN, who controls cache-expire settings?  If CDN server controls cache expire, what is the default value?

Note: My local javascript caching is for 1 day

Answer (score 0):

> But when we use CDN, who controls cache-expire settings?

The CDN that is serving the resource.

> If CDN server controls cache expire, what is the default value?

That would depend on each CDN and for how long they instructed the browser to cache the resource. For example with Google [jquery](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js) they serve it with 1 year Expires header in the future:

```
Expires:Fri, 20 Mar 2015 07:44:29 GMT
```

So it will all depend on the CDN you choose and how it is configured. But in general CDN is used for non-dynamic resources that don't change quite often like a fixed jQuery version which will practically never change.